# Пропадают данные в ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

Всем привет. помогите пожалуйста разобраться.
Есть кластер кликхауса из 4х машин 2х2. Создана таблица ReplicationMergeTree. Над ней Distibuted таблица. Insert делается в таблицу ReplicationMergeTree. Выборка из Distributed таблицы. Проблема в том, что кол-во записываемых строк не совпадает с тем, что отдает select. Смотрел по логам кликхауса - сообщение 
"Wrote block with ID .... N Rows". Тут количество сходится с ожидаемым. 
Если заменить ReplicationMergeTree на MergeTree, то такой проблемы нет. в чем может быть проблема? где искать? 
спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть две возможные причины, по которым это может происходить.

1. Дедупликация данных при вставке.

> Блоки данных дедуплицируются. При многократной записи одного и того же
>   блока данных (блоков данных одинакового размера, содержащих одни и те
>   же строчки в одном и том же порядке), блок будет записан только один
>   раз. Это сделано для того, чтобы в случае сбоя в сети, когда
>   клиентское приложение не может понять, были ли данные записаны в БД,
>   можно было просто повторить запрос INSERT. При этом не имеет значения,
>   на какую реплику будут отправлены INSERT-ы с одинаковыми данными. То
>   есть, обеспечивается идемпотентность INSERT-ов. Это работает только
>   для последних 100 вставленных в таблицу блоков.

В логе этому будут соответствовать сообщения

> Block with ID ... already exists; ignoring it

2. Некорректная настройка репликации или конфигурация кластера. Если реплики не могут скачать друг с друга данные, то будет выводиться соответствующее сообщение в лог. Попытки скачивания данных можно найти по словам Fetching part ...

Comment: Да, проблема решена. действительно схлопывались данные при дедупликации